# ReadField with complextype in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have this Class:

```
public class Stripe implements WritableComparable<Stripe>{
    private List<Term> occorrenze = new ArrayList<Term>();

    public Stripe(){}

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {

    }
}


public class Term implements WritableComparable<Term> {

    private Text key;
    private IntWritable frequency;

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.key.readFields(in);
        this.frequency.readFields(in);
    }
```

Stripe is a List of Term (pair of Text and intWritable).
how can I set the method "readField" for read the complex type Stripe from DataInput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize an list you'll need to write out the length of the list, followed by the elements themselves. A simple readFields / write method pair for Stripe could be:

```
@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    occorrenze.clear();
    int cnt = in.readInt();
    for (int x = 0; x < cnt; x++) {
        Term term = new Term();
        term.readFields(in);
        occorrence.add(term);
    }
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(occorrenze.size());
    for (Term term : occorrenze) {
        term.write(out);
    }
}
```

You could make this more efficient by using a VInt rather than an int, and by using a pool of Terms which can be re-used to save on object creation / garbage collection in the `readFields` method

Answer (score 0):

You could use ArrayWritable which is a list of writables of the same type.